# Google Cloud App Engine Flex deployment error

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm receiving the error when deploying the flex version .net core app to GCP.
I've additionally tested via `gcloud app deploy` and getting the exact same issue. In the logs there are multiple errors all with `audit_log, method: "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion"`, with `status { code: 13 }`, added below.
There doesn't seem to be any other logs to help investigation.
Any advice please?

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 13
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "serviceAccountKeyName": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/xxxxxx/serviceAccounts/xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2021-01-21T15:32:15.695398Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "appengine.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "apps/xxxxxxxx/services/default/versions/XYZ",
        "permission": "appengine.versions.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "apps/xxxxxxxx/services/default/versions/XYZ",
    "serviceData": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.AuditData",
      "createVersion": {
        "request": {
          "parent": "apps/xxxxxxxx/services/default",
          "version": {
            "id": "XYZ",
            "automaticScaling": {
              ....
            },
            "resources": {
              ....
            },
            "runtime": "aspnetcore",
            "env": "flex",
            "servingStatus": "SERVING",
            "envVariables": {
              "GCLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER": "xxxxxxx"
            },
            "readinessCheck": {
              ....
            },
            "livenessCheck": {
              ....
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        ....
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "crndlud361i",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      ....
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-01-21T15:32:15.695398Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/xxxxxxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-21T15:32:15.683297004Z"
}
```

Comment: hey there, can you include more information about the terraform scripts you are running? any webpage where they make a similar deployment to yoursif possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raised a ticket with Google to advise on the issue. I'm not sure the guys got to the bottom of it, however what sorted it in the end was this recommendation:

> Can you try to disable and enable again `App Engine Admin API` in
> Console->Api & Services section and try to deploy again? If it doesn't
> help try to also disable/enable `Google App Engine Flexible Environment` API and try again.

Update: G guys got to the bottom of it. It was a permission removed for a `App Engine Flexible Environment Service Agent` role.
Google engineers confirmed they will look into improving an error details.